# Exchange Notes connector is appending Domino Domain to external email addresses

Tags: exchange

We are currently migrating to Exchange 2003 from Lotus Domino 7.  I have the Notes connector installed, directory synchronization is happening and mail is being routed between the two domains nicely.  All inbound internet email is being routed through our Domino server and is correctly delivered to Exchange users.

However when an exchange user receives one of these external emails, our Notes domain name is being appended to the sender's address. For instance an exchange user who receives a message from username@gmail.com will show username@gmail.com@LOTUSDOMAIN in the To field instead.

This is causing problems when Exchange users reply to emails received from external senders.

Is it possible to somehow stop appending @LOTUSDOMAIN to all external email addresses?

Comment: really exchange 2003? that is so not right?  Also look in the smtp connection doc of the lotus server theres a field for appending a domain name.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at that.  Btw, we just upgraded from NT4 to Server2003 about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: yes if it gets the job done then it probably doesn't matter what you run!

Comment: Yes, relative to the world we're almost a decade behind but as far as we're concerned we just entered the 21st century!  I couldn't find anything about appending the domain name in the smtp connection document.  We decided to just use Exchange as our inbound SMTP server.

Comment: yep that will work!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is addressed here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255160